# Distribution of Similar objects to different persons

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute 5 apples and 5 oranges to 5 people such that each one of them gets exactly 2 fruits.

I worked as follows.
Since each person has three choices for getting a pair of fruits namely
(a)Apple and Apple
(b)Orange and Orange
(c)Apple and Orange

and there are 5 persons so in total, 3^5=243.
Is my analysis and solution correct?

Comment: No, you'd be counting uncompatible cases. Such as "everyone gets two apples" which is impossible because max is 5

Comment: Consider the case of two apples, two oranges and two people; your argument would give $3^2=9$ ways, but they're less: (AA,OO), (AO,AO), (OO,AA).

Answer (score 3):

$$5A/5O$$

Now, we can have $5$ $(A,O)$ pairs, $3$ $(A,O)$ pairs or 1 $(A,O)$ pair. (Try to think why even number of pairs aren't possible)

Case 1 - 5 (A,O) pairs
Only 1 way clearly

Case 2 - 3 (A,O) pairs, 1 (A,A) and 1 (O,O)
This is same as the number of ways to arrange all the letters in the word AOMMM which is equal to $\frac{5!}{3!}=20$

Case 3 - 1 (A,O) pair, 2 (A,A) and 2 (O,O)
This is same as the number of ways to arrange all the letters in the word AOAOM which is equal to $\frac{5!}{2!\times2!}=30$

Therefore a total of 51 ways to distribute

Edit: In Case 2 and 3 they are same as arranging the letters because if you arrange the people in a definite order and then just calculate all the possible ways to assign them a pair.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are counting situations that are impossible, such as everybody getting 2 apples.

Here's one idea I had but am not sure is correct. I believe there are 3 types of situations you could end up with:

One person with two apples, one person with two oranges, three people with one of each.

Two people with two apples, two people with two oranges, one person with one of each.

Everybody has one of each.

And that count would be $${5\choose1}{4\choose1}+{5\choose2}{3\choose2}+1=51$$

Comment: Can we solve it using the concept of generating functions?